# HTML 5 Video not even showing on mobile

Tags: android, html, iphone, video, mobile

[Homepage](https://kavitacijabeograd.com) of my moms website, if you open in browser and use console to see the mobile version you will see the video playing... but when you use your actual phone and type this website there is nothing... not even a frozen thumbnail ....... like what the actual functionality ??
Please help I'm so frustrated.... no errors no nothing......

```
    <div class="mobileVideo">
            <video id="video" playsinline autoplay loop muted width="auto" height="auto" 
    preload="auto" style="display:block;" autoplay="autoplay">
                <source src="" type="video/mp4">
                <source src="https://kavitacijabeograd.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/Mobile-Kavitacijabeograd.m4v"
 type="video/ogg">
           </video>
        </div>
```

Comment: It seems type="video/ogg" works on ,lets say chrome inspect console mobile view, and not work on actual mobile, so I switched to type video/mp4 which is showing. Hope this helps someone in the future

Answer (score 0):

Conclusion,

type="video/ogg" is showing while inspecting the page and the video on PC google chroom,
but when you open website on actual phone, video is not showing unless type is video/mp4

hope it helps some1